# Java - Specific .contain() logic

Tags: java, search, logic

I'm reading multiple string and adding them to `Vector` which looks like this.

```
public void readCode(){
    BufferedReader abc;
    try {
        abc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("code.txt"));
        String line;
        while((line = abc.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
        }
        abc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    for(int i = 0;i<lines.size();i++){
        String x=lines.get(i);
        String[] split = x.split("#");
        vkCode.add(split[0]);
        vkName.add(split[1]);
    }
}
```

And then i'm using this code to find the item code of certain item name.

```
String cmpre="";
    banding = sc.nextLine();
    int target = -1;
    for(int p = 0;p<vkName.size();p++){
        if(vkName.get(p).toString().toLowerCase().contains(cmpre)){
            target=p;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(target==-1){
       System.out.println("Item does not exist!");
    }
    else{
       System.out.println("Item Code is : "+vkCode.get(target));
    }
```

So far the code works just fine , but there is a problem. 
Let say the list of item looks like this.
Edit requested:
Data Sample

```
1213112#PT ABC Syariah Tbk
1212112#PT ABC Tbk
1241312#PT ABC Central Tbk
```

Case 1:
If we try to find `ABC` the expected result is `PT ABC Tbk` ID which is `1212112` but due to my code it will result in `PT ABC Syariah Tbk` ID instead
Case 2:
If we try to find `Syariah ABC` it will not return any code at all. Due to the textfile having `ABC Syariah` which is a problem too.

Comment: Well what do you want to output?  Do you want to find every entry containing the word `Milk`?  Or something else?

Comment: Unless you check for `equals`, you can get multiple results for each search query. You can do both, that is check to see if a value exists that is `equal`, if not then return the one that `contain` the string. You might want to handle the scenario where you get more than one results for contains.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen okay here is actually the real problem, im using dummy data so its probably not understood well. There is ID and Company Name, for example there are PT ABC Tbk, and there is PT ABC Syariah Tbk. If they inserted ABC , they want the PT ABC Tbk ID while if they Type ABC Syariah they want the Syariah Code, but if  u typed ABC there is a chance it might return syariah code if its placed upper than the normal ABC. I Hope it clarifies it.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us some clear data and search terms, along with what should or should not be matching.  The information you gave in the comment belongs in your question, and your question is still not clear to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Edited as requested.

Comment: When searching for `ABC`, I still don't understand the logic by which you expect one of the three inputs.  But I do see the coding problem; you're in a loop, and you don't know when to break, and for which match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen exactly, i break as soon as i found the first match. Which im wondering if there is alternate logic to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First generate a collection of fuzzy matches using .contains(). Then, from that collection, generate a second collection of exact matches using .equals(). Then return the first exact match if there is one, else return the first fuzzy match if there is one, else null.

Comment: So basically i need to collect all data with the same name to a vector and then redo the search from there?

Comment: Yes. Another approach is to create a collection of matches, each with a score based on how exact the match is. In the simplest case, a fuzzy match would get score 1, and an exact match score 2. Then scan the collection and return the highest scoring match.